# Cucumber vs Rspec what to use to check user permissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, cucumber, cancan

I'm using devise and cancan to ensure protection to some areas of my website.

What tool is best to check that a user with a role can access and another role cannot?
Actually I'm creating several cucumber features to make sure a user with admin role can see the page and all other roles cannot (receiving an error message). Is there a better way to do that?

I've read a lot about when to use cucumber over rspec and when user rspec over cucumber, and the general idea I got is that I should say with cucumber "the user says this" and with rspec make sure that under the hood all is working properly... by the way it's hard to apply this general concept at work, and to be honest I find it to be a waste of time. If I can check the final page is what is expected why should I test, for example, for controllers? I find it only worth it to test for model validations and model functions.

Any suggestion? Possibly something more practical than the RSpec book since I have to apply concepts asap.

Comment: have you looked at The Testing-Abilities section of the cancan wiki?  https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Testing-Abilities It has a pretty good primer

Comment: yeah, I missed the "controller testing" section. In fact I have tests to check for right permissions but you know, tests should also cover the controller since you may miss the "authorize!" method allowing anyone to access the resource. I'm about to give it a try

Comment: BTW there are also listed both cucumber and rspec testings... what should I prefer? Of course both is senseless since I want to test it once.

Comment: What I do is cover all the abilities in Rspec, and then just a couple of high level tests with capybara to make I authorize each action (Basically I use factory girl to give me a base level admin, and then try to call the highest level admin function in each controller, and make sure I get Redirected with an access denied)

Comment: It seems interesting and what I am looking for, could you please expand this inside an answer maybe with some more detail or an example? This way I will also be able to select your reply to mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding from the comments.

Based on https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Testing-Abilities I do the following to test.

Inside my Administrator spec .

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'cancan/matchers'

describe Administrator do
 describe "abilities" do
    subject { ability }
    let(:ability) { Ability.new(admin) }
    let(:account) { FactoryGirl.create :account, isp: admin.isp }

    context "is a helpdesk admin" do
      let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create :helpdesk_admin }
      let(:mail_user) {FactoryGirl.create :mail_user, account: account}
      let(:web_user) {FactoryGirl.create :web_user, account: account }
      let(:radius_user) { FactoryGirl.create :radius_user, account: account}

      it { should be_able_to(:change_password,mail_user)}
      it { should be_able_to(:change_password,radius_user)}
      it { should be_able_to(:change_password,web_user)}
      it { should_not be_able_to(:manage, Account.new) }
    end

    context "is a realm admin" do
      let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create :realm_admin }
      it{ should be_able_to(:manage, MailDomain.new)}
      it{ should be_able_to(:manage, RadiusDomain.new)}
      it{ should be_able_to(:manage, WebDomain.new)}
      it{ should be_able_to(:manage, Administrator.new)}
    end
end
```

This lets me test the abilities that Each Role has assigned

Then inside my features/  I do something like this for each controller, to make sure that I don't forget an authorize.

```
context "regular admin" do
    let(:admin) {FactoryGirl.create(:admin)}
     before(:each) do
      visit login_path
      fill_in "email" , with: admin.email
      fill_in "password", with: admin.password
      click_button "Sign in"
    end

     it "shoudln't allow them to add new admins" do 
       visit new_administrator_path
       page.should have_content "You are not authorized to access this page."
     end

  end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this very helpful answer. Just one last thing: how do you make sure you didn't forget an `authorize!` on :create/:update/:delete actions? That methods could be called using another tool, such as `curl` without passing for any user interface.

Comment: This app uses `load_and_authorize_resource :through => :current_isp` so that handles all actions.  If you are only authorizing specific actions in your controller you would need to code tests for each action to verify that you didn't forget.

Comment: Yeah I needed to call it in every action because otherwise my tests were not running properly using Devise login. Can you add an example  for the :delete method? What should I test there? Of course there is no message because there is no UI. Should I test that the status is different from 200? Should I follow a redirect or have a different response code?

Comment: see here: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Authorization-in-Web-Services  in your API calls you can rescue the CanCan::AccessDenied exception and then return 403. So i would just test that you get a 403 when they try to create.

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber is better for business case testing e.g. Bill can't edit Ben's profile. RSpec may be better for more exhaustive analysis, though one would hope you can trust that both Devise and CanCan have done this for you.

I have a sample project that shows some interesting ways of using Cucumber to do work with authentication so you can write very simple features. It would not take much to extend these ideas to usage with roles. Hope its of some use

[see here](https://github.com/diabolo/r3-mongo-devise)